# System32 opens on startup

Tags: windows-7

I have Windows 7 x64 SP1 and when my OS started, Explorer with C:\Windows\system32 opens. What is it?

May it be a virus?

Comment: Related (dupe?): "[C:\Program Files\Microsoft opens at startup](http://superuser.com/questions/22034/c-program-files-microsoft-opens-at-startup)"

Comment: No, I have Win 7 and system 32

Comment: I understand (that's why I didn't flag it to be closed as a dupe), but the problem in that question can have many of the same causes/solutions (primarily an improperly quoted entry in an auto-run area someplace). If you haven't already, I'd suggest go check out the answers there, as many are worth considering/looking into for your case as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Microsoft Help article is for other OS, but is likely to be relevant: [System32 Folder Opens When Logging on to Windows XP, Windows 2000, or Windows NT 4.0](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=170086)

> **Symptom:** When you log on to Microsoft Windows, a Microsoft Windows Explorer window may open that displays the contents of the System32 folder.
>
> This behavior also occurs if there is a String value that contains only a single quote character (") as the Value data in the following Registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
>
> **Cause:** This behavior can occur if a null, incomplete, or damaged entry exists in the registry.
>
> **Resolution:** Use Registry Editor to view the following two Windows registry keys:
>
> - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
> - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
>
> Verify that all the values in these keys do not contain any incorrect, incomplete, or null entries (such as "").

Comment: No, I seen this article, but I haven't anything in theese keys

Answer (score 0):

I believe I may have found a fix [here](http://forums.techguy.org/windows-xp/800350-solved-windows-explorer-opens-c.html), and it seems that Internet Explorer is the culprit. It will have you download [this](http://www.mvps.org/sramesh2k/IEFIX.htm) file and use the following directions.

> To use the VBS Files: Download .vbs file and save it to your hard
>   drive (you may want to right click and use Save Target As). Double
>   click the vbs file. You will be prompted when the script is done.
>
> NOTE: If your anti-virus software warns you of a "malicious" script,
>   this is normal if you have "Script Safe" or similar technology
>   enabled. These scripts are not malicious, but they do make changes to
>   the System Registry.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a program or shortcut in your startup folder that opens the folder. Look in `C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\` and ensure there is noting there that opens the folder.